# Scons: customize default builders

Tags: c, build, scons

I have an embedded software entirely written in C and Assembly and for its build process I am using Scons and GCC. The source code is organized in different folders and each folder represents a "standalone" sub-project (i.e., application elf, static libray, etc.).

The main SConstruct file, located inside the main folder of the project, builds a default environment, adding to it some compilation flags shared among all the sub-projects, then it invokes the SConscripts placed in every sub-project, exporting the default environment.

Each sub-project builds a new environment cloning the default one and customize it with new builders, new compilation flags, etc.

The issue comes out because I have to add, for all sub-projects, some actions after each object file's compilation. In short, I need to generate preprocessed file for each ".c" and ".S", invoking the preprocessor with the same flags used by the normal compilation. To do this I think the best solution is to add the compilation flag "-save-temps=obj" to the default environment (this flag tell to the compiler to keep the temporary files), so all sub-projects will inherit this behavior.

The issue is that SCons doesn't track each generated temporary file. Considering that:

- for each .c file, gcc will create the two temporary file .i and .s
- for each .S file, gcc will create the single temporary file .s

I need to add to the default Object builder:

- A SideEffect to tell scons that a .c to .o compilation will create also a .i file;
- A SideEffect to tell scons that a .c to .o compilation will create also a .s file;
- A SideEffect to tell scons that a .S to .o compilation will create also a .s file;

Is there a way to do this only using the file suffixes and without the enumeration of each target object file?

Furthermore, on each temporary file, I need to invoke a custom tool, again with the same compilation flags used for its compilation, in order to create other files with other debug information. How can I do this? Is there a way to add a post-action to the Object builder?

Thanks,

Ciro

Comment: When you add "-save-temps=obj" is the path and name of the created .s and .i files predictable?  Also you'll likely want to add these files in the emitter and not as SideEffects if they are sources to other builders.  For your custom tool, you'd create a builder and it can use some of the compiler flags.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Anyway the path is known, because "=obj" tells to Gcc to put the file in the same directory of object files. I have some questions about the solution you proposed. Can I modify the emitter of default Object builder?  Has the default object builder an emitter implemented by default? If yes, can I safely overwrite it?

Comment: You can add additional emitters to add more targets and avoid overwriting any existing ones. You do have to reach a bit into the internals to do so.  Feel free to hop on the discourse channel and ask for help. https://discord.gg/bXVpWAy